# How to improve performance of SQL MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, heat, data-synchronization

I have a job that I am currenlty running to sync data between two databases on different internal servers. The one server is the backend database for the HEAT product from FrontRange. The second is our own reporting database we are using for report writing and other internal uses.

Our first approach at the job went something like this:
Query all the data from the HEAT database tables we wanted and populate local temp tables. Then copy that data out to the appropriate table. That would work but they use to TRUNCATE the table every time and repopulate without doing anything for indexes or fragmentation. So I thought well this could be a good candidate to use the SQL merge statement.

So our second approach used a merge statement for each of the tables. It greatly improved the speed of the process but it seems to be locking the source table up so that users are noticing 15-30 second delays when they try to save information. To make the merge only handle records that have had changes or are new I added the BINARY_CHECKSUM function on the select and store it on my side so that I can avoid updating records that haven't changed. Seems expensive though to call that for every record. This table has about ~300k records.

I am wondering is there a better approach to try and synchronize these two tables that I am overlooking. My only constraint is that I really do not want to change anything on the source tables because it is a third party application.

Here is my mege statement I am using for the CallLog table:

```
-- Merge CallLog
MERGE INTO [CallLog] AS T
USING (
        SELECT
            [CallID], [CustID], [CustType], [CallType], [Tracker], [CallStatus], [Priority], [CDuration], [CallCount], [StopWatch], [ClosedBy],
            [ClosedDate], [ClosedTime], [Cause], [CallDesc], [CloseDesc], [RecvdBy], [RecvdDate], [RecvdTime], [ModBy], [ModDate], [ModTime],
            [DTLastMod], [CallSource], [PriorityName], [QuickCall], [Category], [TotalAsgnmntTime], [CatHeading], [TotalJournalTime],
            [TotalTime], [SL_Warn_Goal], [SL_Warn_Date], [SL_Warn_Time], [SL_Complete_Goal], [SL_Complete_Date], [SL_Complete_Time],
            [SL_Clock_Status], [SL_Button_Status], [FirstResolution], [SL_Complete_Status], [SubCallType], [ImpactValue], [ImpactName],
            [UrgencyValue], [UrgencyName], [LinkedToProblem], [LinkedToProblemCustID], [LinkedToProblemName], [LinkedToProblemBy],
            [LinkedToProblemDate], [LinkedToProblemTime], [SLAStatus], [issue_text], [issue_number], [ResCheck], [AsgnAckBy], [AsgnAckDate],
            [AsgnAckTime], [Resolvedby], [ResolvedDate], [ResolvedTime], [ACheck], [ACKEmail], [LinkedToChange], [LinkedToChangeCustID],
            [LinkedToChangeName], [LinkedToChangeBy], [LInkedToChangeDate], [LinkedToChangeTime], [IssueTypeProblem], [IssueTypeChange],
            [RespWarningD], [RespWarningT], [RespMissedD], [RespMissedT], [ResoWarningD], [ResoWarningT], [ResoMissedD], [ResoMissedT],
            [IssueType], [SubCategory], [Diagnosis], [HSSAlert], [ErrorMessage], [ProblemType], [diagnosising], [KB], [CloseStatus],
            [SuggestedAssignGrp], [DefaultGrp], [DefaultGrpTF], [OtherAssign], [WorkAround], [ChangeReason], [CloseProblem], [AssgnApp],
            [AssgnAppRes], [DenyChk], [ImplementationApp], [ImplementationAppRes], [WorkAroundChk], [NoDenyChk], [ImpNoDenyChk],
            [ImpDenyChk], [ChangeStatus], [ReadyToClose], [ResolveOrReAssign], [TicketLabel], [CatCallType], [IssueType_PK], [Category_PK],
            [SubCategory_PK], [CallType_PK], [SubCallType_PK], BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS [Checksum]
        FROM
            [CHLA-HEATDB].SDIT.dbo.calllog
    ) AS S
ON (T.[CallID] = S.[CallID])
WHEN MATCHED AND T.[Checksum] <> S.[Checksum] THEN 
    UPDATE SET
        T.[CallID] = S.[CallID], T.[CustID] = S.[CustID], T.[CustType] = S.[CustType], T.[CallType] = S.[CallType],
        T.[Tracker] = S.[Tracker], t.[CallStatus] = S.[CallStatus], T.[Priority] = S.[Priority], T.[CDuration] = S.[CDuration],
        T.[CallCount] = S.[CallCount], T.[StopWatch] = S.[StopWatch], T.[ClosedBy] = S.[ClosedBy],
        T.[ClosedDate] = S.[ClosedDate], T.[ClosedTime] = S.[ClosedTime], T.[Cause] = S.[Cause], T.[CallDesc] = S.[CallDesc],
        T.[CloseDesc] = S.[CloseDesc], T.[RecvdBy] = S.[RecvdBy], T.[RecvdDate] = S.[RecvdDate], T.[RecvdTime] = S.[RecvdTime],
        T.[ModBy] = S.[ModBy], T.[ModDate] = S.[ModDate], T.[ModTime] = S.[ModTime], T.[DTLastMod] = S.[DTLastMod],
        T.[CallSource] = S.[CallSource], T.[PriorityName] = S.[PriorityName], T.[QuickCall] = S.[QuickCall],
        T.[Category] = S.[Category], T.[TotalAsgnmntTime] = S.[TotalAsgnmntTime], T.[CatHeading] = S.[CatHeading],
        T.[TotalJournalTime] = S.[TotalJournalTime], T.[TotalTime] = S.[TotalTime], T.[SL_Warn_Goal] = S.[SL_Warn_Goal],
        T.[SL_Warn_Date] = S.[SL_Warn_Date], T.[SL_Warn_Time] = S.[SL_Warn_Time], T.[SL_Complete_Goal] = S.[SL_Complete_Goal],
        T.[SL_Complete_Date] = S.[SL_Complete_Date], T.[SL_Complete_Time] = S.[SL_Complete_Time],
        T.[SL_Clock_Status] = S.[SL_Clock_Status], T.[SL_Button_Status] = S.[SL_Button_Status],
        T.[FirstResolution] = S.[FirstResolution], T.[SL_Complete_Status] = S.[SL_Complete_Status],
        T.[SubCallType] = S.[SubCallType], T.[ImpactValue] = S.[ImpactValue], T.[ImpactName] = S.[ImpactName],
        T.[UrgencyValue] = S.[UrgencyValue], T.[UrgencyName] = S.[UrgencyName], T.[LinkedToProblem] = S.[LinkedToProblem],
        T.[LinkedToProblemCustID] = S.[LinkedToProblemCustID], T.[LinkedToProblemName] = S.[LinkedToProblemName],
        T.[LinkedToProblemBy] = S.[LinkedToProblemBy], T.[LinkedToProblemDate] = S.[LinkedToProblemDate],
        T.[LinkedToProblemTime] = S.[LinkedToProblemTime], T.[SLAStatus] = S.[SLAStatus], T.[issue_text] = S.[issue_text],
        T.[issue_number] = S.[issue_number], T.[ResCheck] = S.[ResCheck], T.[AsgnAckBy] = S.[AsgnAckBy],
        T.[AsgnAckDate] = S.[AsgnAckDate], T.[AsgnAckTime] = S.[AsgnAckTime], T.[Resolvedby] = S.[Resolvedby],
        T.[ResolvedDate] = S.[ResolvedDate], T.[ResolvedTime] = S.[ResolvedTime], T.[ACheck] = S.[ACheck],
        T.[ACKEmail] = S.[ACKEmail], T.[LinkedToChange] = S.[LinkedToChange], T.[LinkedToChangeCustID] = S.[LinkedToChangeCustID],
        T.[LinkedToChangeName] = S.[LinkedToChangeName], T.[LinkedToChangeBy] = S.[LinkedToChangeBy],
        T.[LInkedToChangeDate] = S.[LInkedToChangeDate], T.[LinkedToChangeTime] = S.[LinkedToChangeTime],
        T.[IssueTypeProblem] = S.[IssueTypeProblem], T.[IssueTypeChange] = S.[IssueTypeChange],
        T.[RespWarningD] = S.[RespWarningD], T.[RespWarningT] = S.[RespWarningT], T.[RespMissedD] = S.[RespMissedD],
        T.[RespMissedT] = S.[RespMissedT], T.[ResoWarningD] = S.[ResoWarningD], T.[ResoWarningT] = S.[ResoWarningT],
        T.[ResoMissedD] = S.[ResoMissedD], T.[ResoMissedT] = S.[ResoMissedT], T.[IssueType] = S.[IssueType],
        T.[SubCategory] = S.[SubCategory], T.[Diagnosis] = S.[Diagnosis], T.[HSSAlert] = S.[HSSAlert],
        T.[ErrorMessage] = S.[ErrorMessage], T.[ProblemType] = S.[ProblemType], T.[diagnosising] = S.[diagnosising],
        T.[KB] = S.[KB], T.[CloseStatus] = S.[CloseStatus], T.[SuggestedAssignGrp] = S.[SuggestedAssignGrp],
        T.[DefaultGrp] = S.[DefaultGrp], T.[DefaultGrpTF] = S.[DefaultGrpTF], T.[OtherAssign] = S.[OtherAssign],
        T.[WorkAround] = S.[WorkAround], T.[ChangeReason] = S.[ChangeReason], T.[CloseProblem] = S.[CloseProblem],
        T.[AssgnApp] = S.[AssgnApp], T.[AssgnAppRes] = S.[AssgnAppRes], T.[DenyChk] = S.[DenyChk],
        T.[ImplementationApp] = S.[ImplementationApp], T.[ImplementationAppRes] = S.[ImplementationAppRes],
        T.[WorkAroundChk] = S.[WorkAroundChk], T.[NoDenyChk] = S.[NoDenyChk], T.[ImpNoDenyChk] = S.[ImpNoDenyChk],
        T.[ImpDenyChk] = S.[ImpDenyChk], T.[ChangeStatus] = S.[ChangeStatus], T.[ReadyToClose] = S.[ReadyToClose],
        T.[ResolveOrReAssign] = S.[ResolveOrReAssign], T.[TicketLabel] = S.[TicketLabel], T.[CatCallType] = S.[CatCallType],
        T.[IssueType_PK] = S.[IssueType_PK], T.[Category_PK] = S.[Category_PK], T.[SubCategory_PK] = S.[SubCategory_PK],
        T.[CallType_PK] = S.[CallType_PK], T.[SubCallType_PK] = S.[SubCallType_PK], T.[Checksum] = S.[Checksum]
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT VALUES
    (
        S.[CallID], S.[CustID], S.[CustType], S.[CallType], S.[Tracker], S.[CallStatus], S.[Priority], S.[CDuration],
        S.[CallCount], S.[StopWatch], S.[ClosedBy], S.[ClosedDate], S.[ClosedTime], S.[Cause], S.[CallDesc], S.[CloseDesc],
        S.[RecvdBy], S.[RecvdDate], S.[RecvdTime], S.[ModBy], S.[ModDate], S.[ModTime], S.[DTLastMod], S.[CallSource],
        S.[PriorityName], S.[QuickCall], S.[Category], S.[TotalAsgnmntTime], S.[CatHeading], S.[TotalJournalTime], S.[TotalTime],
        S.[SL_Warn_Goal], S.[SL_Warn_Date], S.[SL_Warn_Time], S.[SL_Complete_Goal], S.[SL_Complete_Date], S.[SL_Complete_Time],
        S.[SL_Clock_Status], S.[SL_Button_Status], S.[FirstResolution], S.[SL_Complete_Status], S.[SubCallType], S.[ImpactValue],
        S.[ImpactName], S.[UrgencyValue], S.[UrgencyName], S.[LinkedToProblem], S.[LinkedToProblemCustID], S.[LinkedToProblemName],
        S.[LinkedToProblemBy], S.[LinkedToProblemDate], S.[LinkedToProblemTime], S.[SLAStatus], S.[issue_text], S.[issue_number],
        S.[ResCheck], S.[AsgnAckBy], S.[AsgnAckDate], S.[AsgnAckTime], S.[Resolvedby], S.[ResolvedDate], S.[ResolvedTime], S.[ACheck],
        S.[ACKEmail], S.[LinkedToChange], S.[LinkedToChangeCustID], S.[LinkedToChangeName], S.[LinkedToChangeBy],
        S.[LInkedToChangeDate], S.[LinkedToChangeTime], S.[IssueTypeProblem], S.[IssueTypeChange], S.[RespWarningD],
        S.[RespWarningT], S.[RespMissedD], S.[RespMissedT], S.[ResoWarningD], S.[ResoWarningT], S.[ResoMissedD], S.[ResoMissedT],
        S.[IssueType], S.[SubCategory], S.[Diagnosis], S.[HSSAlert], S.[ErrorMessage], S.[ProblemType], S.[diagnosising], S.[KB],
        S.[CloseStatus], S.[SuggestedAssignGrp], S.[DefaultGrp], S.[DefaultGrpTF], S.[OtherAssign], S.[WorkAround], S.[ChangeReason],
        S.[CloseProblem], S.[AssgnApp], S.[AssgnAppRes], S.[DenyChk], S.[ImplementationApp], S.[ImplementationAppRes],
        S.[WorkAroundChk], S.[NoDenyChk], S.[ImpNoDenyChk], S.[ImpDenyChk], S.[ChangeStatus], S.[ReadyToClose],
        S.[ResolveOrReAssign], S.[TicketLabel], S.[CatCallType], S.[IssueType_PK], S.[Category_PK], S.[SubCategory_PK],
        S.[CallType_PK], S.[SubCallType_PK], S.[Checksum]
    );
GO
```

Comment: I just discovered that the source database is actually SQL 2005 not 2008 so the answer presented below, though a very good option, unfortunately is not available to me for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on SQL 2008,  how about [Change Data Capture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?  You can get the net changes over a period of time and deal only with that (as opposed to replication which pushes every change, even if you update the same data 10 times).

Comment: That sounds great. Can you elaborate a little as to what direction I would go in to get this information. I am not familiar with all of the features of sql 2008.

Comment: I didn't realize that Change Data Capture was the name of the feature since it was all in lowercase. I have found some information on it and am reading it now. But this looks great. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I will also mention that there is another option besides Change Data Capture (CDC) which is Change Data Tracking (CDT). It is less intense than CDC because it doesn't track all the historical changes. It just keeps the primary keys of the records that have changed in the tables being monitored. If you are just trying to synchronize current data this is probably the better option.

Comment: I think my problem was primarily constrained by a poorly indexed source database that we could not change. But I marked this as the answer since you did point me in a direction of something that I was not familiar with and will use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve performance by figuring out what rows to modify/insert before the merge statement.

You can create a temp table  that contains the CallID's that should be affected.
Perhaps something like this.

```
;with cteSource as
(
  select
    S.CallID,
    binary_checksum(*) as [CheckSum]
  from [CHLA-HEATDB].SDIT.dbo.calllog
)  
select
  S.CallID,
  S.[CheckSum]
into #TmpSource
from cteSource as S    
  left outer join CallLog as T
    on S.CallID = T.CallID and
       S.[CheckSum] = T.[CheckSum]
where T.CallID is null
```

Then you can use that table in your `using` select statement.

```
MERGE INTO [CallLog] AS T
USING (
        SELECT
            [CallID], 

            -- A lot of fields

            T.[CheckSum] AS [Checksum]
        FROM
            [CHLA-HEATDB].SDIT.dbo.calllog as C
              inner join #TmpSource as Tmp
                on C.CallID = Tmp.CallID
    ) AS S
ON (T.[CallID] = S.[CallID])
WHEN MATCHED THEN -- Probably don't need this AND T.[Checksum] <> S.[Checksum] THEN 
    UPDATE SET
        T.[CallID] = S.[CallID],
        -- More fields here
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT VALUES
    (
        S.[CallID], 
        -- More fields here
    );
```